# Divide the cells by the length of the same column

Tags: r, matrix

### for example I have two matrix:
test:

```
 Var1 Var2 Var3
  1    3    5
  2    4    6
```

test2:

```
Var1 Var2 Var3
 -5   10   -6
  4   20   -5
```

I want to divide the cells of the first matrix by the length of the same columns of the second matrix that are positive.

Finally, I want to get to this matrix

```
Var1 Var2   Var3
 1/1   3/2   5/0
 2/1   4/2   6/0
```

The numbers in the denominator denote the value of the length of the second matrix that were positive

Answer (score 1):

```r
test <- matrix(1:6, nrow = 2)
test2 <- matrix(c(-5, 10, -6, 4, 20, -5), nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE)
d <- apply(test2, 2, function (x) sum(x > 0))
t(t(test) / d)
```

Output:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1  1.5  Inf
[2,]    2  2.0  Inf
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `colSums` to count positive values column-wise in second matrix and divide it with first matrix using `sweep`.

```
sweep(mat1, 2, colSums(mat2 > 0), `/`)

#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1  1.5  Inf
#[2,]    2  2.0  Inf
```

Answer (score 1):

In `base R`, we can also replicate the column sums of logical vector to makes the lengths same and then divide

```
test/colSums(test2 > 0)[col(test2)]
```

---

Or take the transpose of 'test', divide by the column sums of logical vector and transpose

```
t(t(test)/colSums(test2 > 0))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1  1.5  Inf
#[2,]    2  2.0  Inf
```

#### data

```
test <- matrix(1:6, nrow = 2)
test2 <- matrix(c(-5, 10, -6, 4, 20, -5), nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE)
```